# WebStorm not AutoComplete local typescript packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webstorm

I'm working with `WebStorm 16.2`, And i am developing node.js application using `TypeScript`.

My application is devided to some local packages that some have dependencies to other local packages(In my package.json's dependencies, it is local path to the packages).

My problem is that webstorm does not autocomplete code when im using classes and methods from my local packages.

**For example:**
Suppose i have in my app package **A** that exports some classes(for Example Animal).
And I have module **B** That his package.json look like:

```
{
  "name": "B",
  "dependencies": {
  "A": "file:../A"
  }
}
```

And when i am trying to use methods of Animal from package A in package B, it will not auto complete.
This is very makes it difficult to work like that in typescript.
Maybe i am doing something wrong? maybe i should configure webstorm when working with local packages?
Thanks alot.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, any insights?

Comment: unfortunately no. I asked in JetBrain support [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000129664-WebStorm-not-AutoComplete-local-typescript-packages) but couldnt find solution to the problem.

Comment: actually after closing Webstorm and open again, things got back to normal.